# Alias for class name in the method

Tags: c#, class, alias, using

I have some curly question..
I can define alias for the class at top of my document, Such as

```
using MyName = Bla.Bla.ClassName
```

But can I define something like this in the method?

Comment: Do you want to write the same syntax inside a method ?

Comment: Syntax may be other. The main reason is to use class ClassName from namespace Bla.Bla in short form (Without namespace in the method.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. If you mean that you want to define 
a class alias inside a method, this is not possible.

Alias could be defined only at file or namespace level:

```
using MyName = Bla.Bla.ClassName;
namespace A{
...
}
```

or

```
namespace A{
    using MyName = Bla.Bla.ClassName
...
}
```

If you instead mean you want to define a "method alias", this also isn't possible: alias are only for types or namespaces.

Answer (score 5):

No, `using` directives have to either be outside any declaration, or within a namespace declaration:

```
using Foo;
namespace Bar
{
   using Baz;
}
```

You can't do this within a method. Why not just do it for the whole class though? Why do you *only* want it to apply within a particular method?

Comment: I have a generic on two type parameters (the Either monad). My methods have several different return branches, each of which returns a "new Either<x,y>(z)". The inner values of Either are readonly, so without an alias I must type "Either<x,y>" every time I want to reference this type. The parameter types "x" and "y" depend on which method I am in, and usually have long names; the "Either<x,y>" takes up over 60 characters in some cases. It would be useful to say, at the beginning of the method, "using either = Either<x,y>" and then "return new either(z)" to reduce clutter.

Comment: While this answer is true for `using` directives for namespaces, it looks like the OP is talking about using (erm) `using` for directive **aliases**, not `using` directives for namespaces. (future readers may be interested in the [using Directive article on docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) for more information on the uses for the `using` directive).

Comment: Also sure, here's a use case. I'm using a library that names its enums `(CompanyName)SomeClassResultSubCategory(PartImActuallyInterestedIn)ResultConstants`, and I am using aliases so intellisense doesn't "helpfully" autocomplete that to `(CompanyName)SomeClassResultSubCategoryWrongResultConstants` causing me to use `HasFlag` on values between enums, which the compiler will allow. I aliased it to something that is far more manageable, though I suppose some kind of generic method may work better in this specific case.